# Insert a single record from a text file into 3 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a generated text file with 70 lines. It's a web form from one of my partner "legacy" platform and this is sent to me by email, on a text file :

```
Name
First Name
First Name + Name
Age
Telephone
City
Country
Email
Website
Profession
Etc
Etc 2
...
```

I want to "split" this text file into 3 records in my MS-SQL database using C# and ASP.NET.

The 3 tables are something like this :

```
Client_General_Information
Client_Private_Information
Client_Request_Problem
```

And I want to target specific lines, for specific tables and fields. Example :

```
Line 1 goes in Table 1 (Name field)
Line 2 goes in Table 1 (First name field)
Line 3 goes in Table 1 (...)
Line 4-5-6 goes in Table 3 ( 3 other fields)
Line 7-9 goes in Table 1 (2 other fields)
Line 10 goes in Table 2 (...)
```

I am searching a way to read the text file, and insert into the values into 3 tables. The text file will always have the same number of lines and will always have same order. Sometimes lines are empty but it is changing from file to file.

So I have my file reader, but I am not sure where to go next :

```
        //Load our text file
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("\\test.txt");

        int NumberOfLines = 70;

        //Make our array for each line
        string[] ListLines = new string[NumberOfLines];

        //Read the number of lines and put them in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfLines; i++)
        {
            ListLines[i] = tr.ReadLine();
        }

        //
        tr.Close();
```

Should I make 3 arrays or 3 lists and insert each one of them ? Just to be clear, I dont want to "bulk insert". Each text file is a unique client !

Thanks

Comment: maintain 3 lists, and insert in the loop from where you are reading in file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate class having the getter and setter methods same as the fields in the 3 tables

```
Client_General_Information
Client_Private_Information
Client_Request_Problem
```

Then read from the file and assign values to respective fields in the objects like

...

```
Client_General_Information newObject = new Client_General_Information ();

int NumberOfLines = 70;

//Make our array for each line
string[] ListLines = new string[NumberOfLines];

//Read the number of lines and put them in the array
 for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfLines; i++)
 {
       ListLines[i] = tr.ReadLine();

 }
 newObject.Name=ListLines[0];
 newObject.LastName=ListLines[1];
```

and so on then insert the data in the database as per your requirement from the objects.